# Intermediate value theorem,

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I am solving the following problem :

> I want to use the Intermediate Value Theorem and Rolle’s theorem to show that the graph of $f(x) = x^3 + 2x + k$ crosses the x-axis exactly once, regardless of the value of the constant k.

I know I can use the intermediate value theorem, but I don't necessarily know how to show the change in a sign for two select inputs. any hero would be appreciated in that regard.

I also know the derivative of $x^3 + 2x + k$ is greater than zero, but what does that mean?

Comment: Your function is strictly monotone increasing, so cannot cross any horizontal line more than once. [That inclludes the $x$ axis.] Being cubic it also crosses each horizontal line at least once.

Comment: Why not choose $ \ x = -k \ $ and $ \ x = k \ \ , \ \ k > 0 \ \ $  and show that those function values have opposite signs?

Comment: for the last question: that means there is no max\min for $f(x)$

Comment: If you know Rolle's theorem, then you surely know the mean value theorem, and that is what tells you that if the derivative is greater than zero, then the function is strictly increasing and hence cannot cross the $x$-axis more than once.  (The IVT shows that it crosses it at least once.)

Comment: yes thank you. I am still trying tp figure out how to implement the IVT

Answer (score 1):

Your function $f(x)=x^3+2x+k$ has derivative $3x^2+2$ which, as you say, is greater than $0$. This means that $f$ is strictly increasing.  This follows from for example the mean value theorem. Now suppose $f$ is $0$ at two distinct points $x$ and $y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$. But we must have either $x<y$ or $y<x$. We can assume $x<y$ and then $f(x)<f(y)$ since $f$ is increasing.

To prove that it has at least one solution, as you say, we use the intermediate value theorem. For any fixed $k$ we can choose $x$ large enough such that $x^3+2x+k>0$. If we choose $x$ large but negative we get $x^3+2x+k<0$. Now it follows from the intermediate value theorem.